# Different Schemas produce Error retrieving data from one or more shards. The underlying error message received was: Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I created an EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE in Azure as an alternative to the inability to created LINKED SERVERS on the Azure platform.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'secretpassword';
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL LinkedServerCredential  
WITH IDENTITY = 'login_name', SECRET = 'login_password-here';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE LinkedProductionDb
WITH
(
   TYPE=RDBMS,
   LOCATION='azure.database.windows.net',
   DATABASE_NAME='ProductionDb',
   CREDENTIAL= LinkedServerCredential
);
```

Everything goes great, no errors and the statements executed successfully. So now I create an EXTERNAL TABLE having the identical table structure as the table that resides in the underlying database defined in the EXTERNAL DATASOURCE; but I want it assigned under a different SCHEMA to be able to distinguish it as a linked table in the targeted database. So I attempt this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [LNK].[Transactions](
    TransactionId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CustomerId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    SubscriptionId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ProductId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    TransType VARCHAR(100),
    TransKind VARCHAR(100),
    Success BIT,
    Amount MONEY,
    GatewayUsed VARCHAR(100),
    RecordImportDate DATETIMEOFFSET,
)
WITH
(
   DATA_SOURCE = LinkedProductionDb
)
GO
```

Now surprisingly, I am able to create this EXTERNAL TABLE without any issue; except for when I attempt to access the data via a simply query. I receive the error: "Error retrieving data from one or more shards.  The underlying error message received was: 'Invalid object name 'LNK.Transactions'.'."

It only took me a few minutes to think about what I'd done and why I received the error. Obviously, since the table in the original database isn't created under the LNK schema; it is an invalid object.

So is there any way or methodical practice that I can use to distinguish my EXTERNAL TABLES from my physical tables within my database?

Obviously, among other things; this is undoubtedly one of the advantages of having separately defined objects as LINKED SERVERS within SQL.

I know I cannot be the only person who see's the benefit of segregating the objects to clearly distinguish them if they both need to reside in the same database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this by creating a view on the external server with the [schema].[table] that i wanted to segregate.  In your case, you'd use create a view called [LNK].[Transactions] in LinkedProductionDb, then everything works.

Comment: Thanks, thats not ideally what I had in mind but I guess its the only reasonable alternative to the problem. Appreciated!

Comment: Good idea. Table names also need to be the same - I was tempted to some naming convention like 'External_Transaction' to the external table, to identity these ones quickly as external tables, but I got the same error..

Comment: This is bad design of the feature. Using linked servers is very simple and natural. But with Azure elastic queries they decided to do it in a very strange way (they didn't built it on top of what's working and known). IMHO the step to create external table should not be needed at all. Anyway thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to create the external table with a different schema from the one used in the external table by using the `WITH` options `SCHEMA_NAME` and `OBJECT_NAME`.

From Microsoft:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name  
( { <column_definition> } [ ,...n ])     
{ WITH ( <rdbms_external_table_options> ) } 
)[;] 

<rdbms_external_table_options> ::= 
  DATA_SOURCE = <External_Data_Source>, 
  [ SCHEMA_NAME = N'nonescaped_schema_name',] -- This is what we want
  [ OBJECT_NAME = N'nonescaped_object_name',] -- ^
```

In the `WITH`, if you specify the `SCHEMA_NAME` and `OBJECT_NAME`, you can name the `EXTERNAL TABLE` something other that how the database with the table names it.

Example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [LNK].[Transactions](
    TransactionId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CustomerId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    SubscriptionId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ProductId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    TransType VARCHAR(100),
    TransKind VARCHAR(100),
    Success BIT,
    Amount MONEY,
    GatewayUsed VARCHAR(100),
    RecordImportDate DATETIMEOFFSET,
)
WITH
(
   DATA_SOURCE = LinkedProductionDb,
   SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo', -- This is the name of the schema on the host database
   OBJECT_NAME = 'Transactions' -- Name of the table on the host database
)
GO
```

Now you can use this table as `LNK.Transations` (assuming the schema `LNK` is valid).